# Toggle div, if already open then hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a toggling panel that once opened, if the active element is clicked again it closes yet if the sibling element is click the content is updated only I'm having mixed results. Can anybody see where im going wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/9b3mecc2/

```
$('.sectors-list li').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
  var order = $(this).index(); 
  $('.sub-sectors div').hide();
  $('.sub-sectors div').eq(order).show(); 
  if($('.digital-sectors').is(':visible')
  && order === 0){
    $('.sub-sectors').removeClass('active'); 
  } else {
      $('.sub-sectors').addClass('active'); 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do is not complicated, just that your code is missing references from the event element to the element to show, so you can do with css, using the pseudo-selector `: target`

Check documentation [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

[Browser support list](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Atarget)

```css
div{ display: none; }
div:target{ display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href='#data-foo'>foo</a></li>
  <li><a href='#data-bar'>bar</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='data-foo'>data foo</div>
<div id='data-bar'>data bar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will works.

```
   $('.sectors-list li').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var order = $(this).index(); 
        $('.sub-sectors div').hide(); 
        // $('.sub-sectors div').eq(order).show(); //moving this line to eles part
        if($('.digital-sectors').is(':visible')
        && order === 0){
            $('.sub-sectors').removeClass('active'); 
        } else {
        $('.sub-sectors').addClass('active'); 
        $('.sub-sectors div').eq(order).show();     
        } 
    });
```